# Помогите написать ссылку ДВССЫЛ

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Прохожу мини-курс по Excel, пытаюсь понять, как работает ДВССЫЛ, просмотрела кучу видео, прочла много статей - так и не поняла.

Изначально проходила этот урок: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOjKlbX3rVA&list=PLsPotgU_ELTqAgQJs8GdTB1yWEkGFdOtz&index=10

То, что в нем на 8:45 у меня не работает.

Потом стала гуглить, но так и не нашла рабочий вариант.

[image: Видео]

[image: Скриншот моего Excel]

Cпасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Все дело в пробеле в названии листа. Добавьте апострофы вокруг имени листа:

```
=ДВССЫЛ("'" & G3 & "'!" & G4)
```

Comment: Я пробовала так и не поняла, к сожалению. Если лист называется "Лист 1", а ячейка нужна на нем, например, B2, то как будет выглядеть ссылка?

Comment: Так: `'Лист 1'!B2`